# Is there a way for checking a certain pattern in a list?

Tags: python, list, design-patterns

is there a way to check for a certain pattern  such that when is use the function the elements in the list fulfilling the pattern can be printed...e.g.

i have a list

```
abc=['adams, brian','smith, will',' and j.smith. there is a long string here','some more strings','some numbers','etc etc']
```

now what i want is that i get all the strings that have the format `'xyz,abc'` and `'x.abc'` out of the list.

it would be a great help if u guys could tell me of a generalized way of how i can look for a certain pattern in a list.

Comment: Pattern matching can be easily achieve by regular expressions. You can then iterate over the list to do the matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = re.compile('(\w+\.\w+)|(\w+,\s?\w+)')
>>> map(exp.findall, abc)
[[('', 'adams, brian')], [('', 'smith, will')], [('j.smith', '')], [], [], []]
```

Functional way of flattening this result:

```
>>> r = map(exp.findall, abc)
>>> filter(None, sum(sum(r, []), ()))
('adams, brian', 'smith, will', 'j.smith')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('^([A-z]*)[,\.](\s*)([A-z]*)$')
filtered = [ l for l in abc if re.match(pattern,l) ]
```